# Send file via BT directly to Image folder in Android devices?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, file-transfer, obex

I don't know how to access folder "Images" on android devies, to send file directly to it.

I'm able to successfully send file using below code, however after research I'm not able to specify "Uri" so I can't receive file in "Image" folder or any other than "Download" which is i think default.

```
var file = @"C:\Users\JDOMINO\Desktop\Personal\Zegarek\1.jpg";
                        var uri = new Uri("obex://" + device.DeviceAddress + "/" + file);
                        var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
                        request.ReadFile(file);
                        var response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                        // check response.StatusCode
                        response.Close();
```

Expected output would be something like to change Uri from "obex://" to "obex://Images/Newfolder" however this doesn't work.

Comment: You can not change distination folder using OBEX Object Push Profile. Only OBEX File Transfer profile allows to change target folders. However, the folders name may be other than real folders on a device.

Comment: Thank You very much